# JUnit 5: execute code once before multiple tests

Tags: kotlin, junit, quarkus, junit5

I'm working on a project which uses Quarkus to spin up a few REST endpoints. I have multiple integration tests which run with different test profiles or completely without a test profile. Heres an example:

```
@QuarkusTest
@Tag("integration")
@TestProfile(SomeProfile::class)
class IntegrationTestWithSomeProfile {
    @Test 
    fun someTest() { ... }
}

@QuarkusTest
@Tag("integration")
class IntegrationTestWithoutProfile {
    @Test 
    fun someTest() { ... }
}
```

Now I would like to execute a piece of code before the first test runs (or after the last test has finished). The problem is that @BeforeAll can only be used per class and I can't use Quarkus' start and stop events since Quarkus is started and shutdown multiple times - once for each different test profile.

Is there any hook (or hack - i don't mind dirty stuff as long as it works) which I could use, which would execute only once at the very beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution I need. It's called `TestExecutionListener`. I went the route with adding a file called `org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` in `resources/META-INF/services`. Inside this file I've put the fqcn of my class implementing the `TestExecutionListener` interface.

In there I can then override `testPlanExecutionStarted()` and `testPlanExecutionFinished()`. With this, it doesn't matter how many TestProfiles we use and how many times Quarkus is started and stopped. The TestExecutionListener runs only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `@QuarkusTestResource` with a class implementing `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager`.
This can be used to start/stop services on the classes you want.

See: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource

Comment: The problem here is still that quarkus is started multiple times when using multiple TestProfiles. However, I was finally able to find a solution which does what I need: TestExecutionListener. It has a testPlanExecutionStarted() function which runs exactly once, no matter how many profiles we use. :)